# Remove Null Columns using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a collection of data and would like to get rid of columns that contains null or empty values. An example should look like this:

```
REGION  | STATE | COUNTY | PROGRAM 1 | PROGRAM 2 | PROGRAM 3 | PROGRAM 4 | ...
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"North" | null  | null   | "Foo"     | null      | "Bar"     | null      |...
"East"  | null  | null   | "Duh"     | null      | "Whew"    | null      |...
```

And the result could be:

```
REGION  | PROGRAM 1 | PROGRAM 3 | ...
-------------------------------------
"North" | "Foo"     | "Bar"     | ...
"East"  | "Duh"     | "Whew"    | ...
```

Note that the null columns are pretty consistent (i.e. STATE is null all the way). As a LINQ newbie, I couldn't quite figure out the proper way of achieving the desired result. Any suggestions/code samples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// get all columns to array 
var columns  = yourDataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray();

foreach(var col in columns) {
    // check column values for null 
    if (yourDataTable.AsEnumerable().All(dr => dr.IsNull(col)))
    {
         // remove all null value columns 
         yourDataTable.Columns.Remove(col);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the columns are consistent, is the question you are asking "How do I select only specific columns?"

```
var result = from x in myTable
select new { x.Region, x.Program1, x.Program3 };
```

Or using extension method format:

```
var result = myTable.Select(x => new { x.Region, x.Program1, x.Program3 });
```